# Freeware DVD to MP4 converter

Tags: gratis, video, media-converter, optical-media

I'm looking for a software that can convert my DVDs into MP4.

I have already found a software that works (Wondershare Video Converter), but unfortunately it only converts 1/3 of the DVD, the full version cost 50€.

Does anyone of you know a software that can convert DVDs to MP4 (protected DVDs too) that is freeware?

Comment: Have you tried VLC?

Comment: Yes I tried it with VLC (recording tool) but the mpeg-video is very strange. It didn't work very well.

Answer (score 6):

I have used [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/) for this.

It is open source and available for Windows, Mac and Linux.

You can set it to transcode the subtitles and / or select sound tracks if these are available on the DVD.

It isn't particularly fast but it does the job.

Comment: I tried it with HandBrake today but the videoquality is very bad. The Audio is also very bad. It didn't work.

Comment: Handbrake is fine - you can raise or lower the quality settings as you see fit, but it will be at the cost of file size.

Answer (score 1):

I use many of DVDVideoSoft's [programs](https://www.dvdvideosoft.com/free-dvd-video-software-download.htm) to manipulate media files.
You could try their [Free DVD Video Converter](https://www.dvdvideosoft.com/products/dvd/Free-DVD-Video-Converter.htm)
Unfortunately it seems it only converts unprotected files. You should also know that it may be illegal to break copy protection depending on where you live.
Also, to get the highest possible quality you may need pay for Premium though.
But try it out and see if the quality satisfies you.

**NOTE:** DVDVideoSoft's products are freeware. DVDVideoSoft may bundle links to other websites and third-party apps installations including toolbars in its products. Make sure to opt-out if you don't want any of those (I don't recommend them myself, but I also bought premium)

Comment: Thanks, I already use the Youtube-to-MP3-Converter. Do you know a Software, where I can convert protected files to unprotected files?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't.

Comment: Seems to want to use an actual DVD for input, so will not accept a directory full of *.VOB files  Otherwise, looks fine (+1)